# How can I web app poll a queue continously? or does it have to be another service?

Tags: java, tomcat, jvm, jms, rabbitmq

If I use a queue in my web application (spring), can I do:

```
while(..)
{

}
```

To response to new items added to a queue, or does this have to be a seperate service that runs on the server?

i.e. this can't be sustained in a web application correct?

Answer (score 0):

You would want your web app to use timers to periodically wake up and poll the server (for example, using an AJAX request if the request is made all the way from the browser).